Color changes when modifying SVG to PNG converted image using image_editor package in Flutter
I’m working on a Flutter project where I need to convert SVG images to PNG and then make some modifications using the image_editor package. However, I’ve encountered an issue where the color of the image changes after making any modifications.
Here’s a brief overview of what I’m doing:

Convert SVG to PNG using flutter_svg package.
Load the PNG image into image_editor.
Apply modifications (e.g., cropping, rotating).
Save the modified image.

After this, the colors in the image appear different from the original. Has anyone else experienced this issue? How can I preserve the original colors while making modifications?
Before:
Before modifications
After:
After modifications
Here’s a snippet of my code:
Future<Uint8List> cropImageDataWithNativeLibrary({
  ExtendedImageEditorState? state,
  Uint8List? imageData,
  double? contrast,
  double? brightness,
  bool isCropDataAvailable = false,
}) async {
  final Rect? cropRect = isCropDataAvailable ? state?.getCropRect() : Rect.zero;
  final EditActionDetails? action = state?.editAction;

  final int rotateAngle = action?.rotateAngle.toInt() ?? 0;

  final Uint8List img = imageData!;

  final ImageEditorOption option = ImageEditorOption();

  if (isCropDataAvailable && action != null && action.needCrop) {
    option.addOption(ClipOption.fromRect(cropRect ?? Rect.zero));
  }

  if (rotateAngle != 0) {
    option.addOption(RotateOption(rotateAngle));
  }
  option.addOption(
    ColorOption(
        matrix: contrastAdjustMatrix(
            value: contrast!, isiOSNative: Platform.isAndroid)),
    newGroup: true,
  );

  option.addOption(
    ColorOption(
        matrix: brightnessAdjustMatrix(
            value: brightness!, isiOSNative: Platform.isAndroid)),
    newGroup: true,
  );

  final Uint8List? result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
    image: img,
    imageEditorOption: option,
  );

  return result!;
}


I used the svg to png converted image in image editor, after doing modifications and saving the changes, I expected the color to remain same, but the color got changed in the modified image.

I think that the resulting image doesn't have alpha supported, the transparent pixels are turned into black, could it be the case?
Can you share the code you use to save the image or display it?
